# Find the matching elements between multiple arrays (more than 2) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 5 arrays:

```
arr1 = ["this", "and", "that", "as", "well"]
arr2 = ["this", "apples", "that", "as", "well"]
arr3 = ["what", "about", "this", "and", "too"]
arr4 = ["maybe", "we", "can", "figure", "out"]
arr5 = ["and", "all", "of", "the", "this"]
```

I know how to get the matching elements between 2 arrays:

```
matches = arr1.filter(element => arr2.includes(element));
```

This would give:

```
[this, that, as, well]
```

I can use a loop to find matches between the first array and all others:

```
all_data = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5]
all_matches = []

all_data.forEach(function(arr, i) {
    all_matches.push(all_data[0].filter(element => arr.includes(element)))
})
```

But how can I find all possible combinations of arrays? Preferably without 2 loops.

Comment: Two loops are required, even if not explicit..

Comment: @user2864740 Figured. Any ideas on an elegant approach (even with 2 loops)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const arr1 = ["this", "and", "that", "as", "well"];
const arr2 = ["this", "apples", "that", "as", "well"];
const arr3 = ["what", "about", "this", "and", "too"];
const arr4 = ["maybe", "we", "can", "figure", "out"];
const arr5 = ["and", "all", "of", "the", "this"];

const all = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5];

const results = all.reduce((a, c) => {
  const nextArrs = all.slice(all.indexOf(c) + 1);
  const dups = c.filter((e) => nextArrs.some(arr => arr.includes(e) && !a.includes(e)));
  return [...a, ...dups];
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

What this does is to go through all the arrays and check if the elements of the current array are included by the arrays that come after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your `forEach` loop on `all_data` to generate a 2-dimensional array of matches between each array (so `all_matches[i-1][j-1]` represents the matches between `arr{i}` and `arr{j}`):

```js
arr1 = ["this", "and", "that", "as", "well"]
arr2 = ["this", "apples", "that", "as", "well"]
arr3 = ["what", "about", "this", "and", "too"]
arr4 = ["maybe", "we", "can", "figure", "out"]
arr5 = ["and", "all", "of", "the", "this"]

all_data = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5]
all_matches = []

all_data.forEach(function(a1, i) {
  all_matches.push([])
  all_data.forEach(function(a2) {
    all_matches[i].push(a1.filter(element => a2.includes(element)))
  })
})

console.log(all_matches)
```